# Есть код, изменения цветовой темы на странице, как записать тему в local storage которую выбрал ползователь

Tags: javascript, css3, dom, localstorage, root

Вот код js, в нём я ставлю/убираю атрибут тегу html

```
themeToggleBtn.addEventListener('click', switchThemeColor);
function switchThemeColor() {
    if (document.documentElement.hasAttribute('theme')){
        document.documentElement.removeAttribute('theme');
    }else {
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('theme', 'color-theme');
    }
}
```

В css записываю эти стили в css переменные и потом эти переменные использую, например для кнокпи

```
.toggle-btn{
  color: var(--button-color);
  и тд
}
```

```
:root {
    --header-bg-color: #FE6F5E;
    --header-title-color: #F2F2F2;
    --nav-bg-color: darkseagreen;
    --li-bg-color: pink;
    --links-color: #ffffff;
    --aside-bg-color: #DF4A32;
    --main-bg-color: #F26522;
    --content-title-color: #ffffff;
    --content-subtitle-color: #ffffff;
    --img-content-color: #ffffff;
    --img-bg-color: #4682b4;
    --button-wrapper-bg-color: #77608d;
    --button-color: #ffffff;
    --button-bd-color: #F26522;
    --button-bg-color: #FE6F5E;
    --button-active-bg-color: #F26522;
}
:root[theme='color-theme']{
    --header-bg-color: #794f45;
    --header-title-color: #0e0e0e;
    --nav-bg-color: #770F05;
    --li-bg-color: #0B6207;
    --links-color: #000000;
    --aside-bg-color: #848484;
    --main-bg-color: #6E7783;
    --content-title-color: #0e0e0e;
    --content-subtitle-color: #000000;
    --img-content-color: #000000;
    --img-bg-color: #D05F04;
    --button-wrapper-bg-color: #000741;
    --button-color: #0e0e0e;
    --button-bd-color: #714AB2;
    --button-bg-color: #956387;
    --button-active-bg-color: #714AB2;
}
```

Comment: Так там для этого всего один метод. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 0):

[Window.localStorage | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

```
themeToggleBtn.addEventListener('click', switchThemeColor);
function switchThemeColor() {
    if (document.documentElement.hasAttribute('theme')){
        document.documentElement.removeAttribute('theme');
        localStorage.removeItem('theme'); // удаляем
    }else {
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('theme', 'color-theme');
        localStorage.setItem('theme', 'color-theme'); // сохраняем
    }
}

// При новом заходе берём сохранённое значение
window.onload = function() {
    if(localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'color-theme'){
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('theme', 'color-theme');
    }
}
```